# What's a verb used for someone or something you can't get enough of?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

The adjective may be "irresistible", but I specifically mean, and am requesting, a **verb**:

Like, for a partner whom you can't get enough. In my language, for example, we literally say, "*you're so amazing, I could never 'thirst' from kissing you*". It doesn't have to be a romantic setting. It could be a song you enjoy a lot - Again, in my language, "*I enjoy this song so much, I could never 'thirst' from listening to it*".

So, in English, what's an (appropriate) verb used as instead of "thirst" (which probably sounds outlandish in English)?

Comment: I could never ***tire*** of ...

Comment: Could you please explain the meaning of your language’s use of what you translate into English as “thirst.” I ask because it does seem outlandish, as it seems to be the opposite of what one would expect, as in “I will still be thirsty (for your kisses) after kissing you.”

Comment: @ferjsoto42yahoocom Sure. When you're "hungry" for a kiss, you just want to keep on kissing. You could never 'thirst' because the person is so tasty and irresistible. As an idiom or in a poetic setting, it will make sense and sound fancy IMO. It's actually not too outlandish, at least not compared to other stuff that are literally translated to English. :)

Answer (score 2):

The verb [tire](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tire) meaning *to become weary*, when used as a phrasal verb [tire of](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tire%20of), works nicely for what you want to say.

> You're so amazing, I could never *tire of* kissing you.

and

> I enjoy this song much, I could never *tire of* listening to it.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot **refrain** from looking at this site for interesting questions.

> Refrain = to avoid doing or stop yourself from doing something
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/refrain)

I might use this as another way of saying the rather obvious “*I cannot resist looking ...*”.

Also consider “*I cannot desist from ... *” or “*I cannot stop ...*”.

> Desist = to stop doing something
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/desist)